# Expected end of statement error

Tags: sql, select, vbscript

I have this VB script that is being ran inside a 3rd party app and is throwing the "Expected End of Statement' Error. Here is the code in question. The select statment works fine in SQL server manager studio.

Thanks.

```
Dim SecurityDB
Set SecurityDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ustcca015s6\Continuum;DATABASE=continuumdb;UID=Andy8796;PWD=xxxx1234;"
SecurityDB.Open Conn
Set EmployeeRS = SecurityDB.Execute "Select count(*) from dbo.personnel where state=1 and lastname not like 'lapt%' and lastname is not NULL and valuelo in (Select ObjectIdLo from area where uiname like 'usmm%' and uiname not like '%gate%') and valuelo <> 1111497912;"
Result = EmployeeRS.GetRows
EmployeeRS.Close
SecurityDB.Close
```

Comment: Don't you need a bracket after Execute? `Set EmployeeRS = SecurityDB.Execute("Select count(*) from dbo.personnel where state=1 and lastname not like 'lapt%' and lastname is not NULL and valuelo in (Select ObjectIdLo from area where uiname like 'usmm%' and uiname not like '%gate%') and valuelo <> 1111497912;")`

Comment: The comment of @RichardTheKiwi is correct: Only a `sub` (routine that do not return a return value) can be called without parenthesis. If you are calling a `function`, then parenthesis are mandatory. See the difference between `MsgBox "Process terminated", vbOKOnly` and `answer = MsgBox("Do you want to terminate the process?", vbYesNo)`

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Thank you; this did fix my error measage. Appears to be pulling in correct data now.

Answer (score 1):

@RichardTheKiwi posted the answer in the comments section two weeks ago but sadly hasn't added it as an answer in the ... answer section. OK, the Point Pimp[ette] is back tonight,  so these questions show up as one step closer to "solved"!

Don't you need a bracket after Execute?

```
Set EmployeeRS = SecurityDB.Execute("Select count(*) from dbo.personnel where state=1 and lastname not like 'lapt%' and lastname is not NULL and valuelo in (Select ObjectIdLo from area where uiname like 'usmm%' and uiname not like '%gate%') and valuelo <> 1111497912;")
```